# How to make VSCode search files inside Jars

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code

I recently moved from Eclipse to VSCode. I am having issues while searching for files(Java files) in VSCode. When I search for files in VSCode using *Cmd+P* it shows me all the files present in Projects except the ones that are present in jars that I am using. For example, I am using many spring jars, but now if I will search for `FrameworkServlet` then it shows *No Result*, [Check this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJQpj.png)
Eclipse used to show the files from the jars but vscode doesn't. Also, I have *File Manager for Java* extension installed. How can I achieve this functionality in VSCode?

Comment: Unlike Eclipse, VSCode is not built for Java development but general code editing, so it won't by default work for Java specific scenarios like locating jar files. You can raise feature requests to see if the extension developers can help https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-dependency/issues

Comment: [The VSCode Java language support _is_ Eclipse](https://twitter.com/howlger/status/1358189525424459777). @LexLi

Answer (score 6):

I researched and found that it can be done by going to command pallet (`cmd+p`), type # and then you can search any class in the project even if it is inside a jar.